# Suspend problem in ubuntu 14.04.02 (Lenovo z510)

Tags: 14.04, suspend, lenovo

I have a Lenovo z510 running Ubuntu 14.04.02.(kernel version = 3.16.0-30-generic)
It has a suspend problem, when I suspend my laptop I can't wake it up properly. Laptop will turn on but screen remain off.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, same laptop, same Ubuntu (Elementary OS Freya, to be exact, but it's based on Ubuntu 14.04). Interestingly enough, suspend/resume works fine on Ubuntu 12.04, which has a 3.13.0 kernel (3.13.0.63 at the moment). Downgrading the kernel on 14.04 to a 3.13 kernel made suspend work again. I haven't tested 3.14 and 3.15. I did test 3.19 (I think) and it had the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution myself. Installing bumblebee worked for me. I'm now using Ubuntu 16.04 and installing bumblebee is a little tricky in 16.04 so I suggest you follow this link to install bumblebee:

http://www.webupd8.org/2016/08/how-to-install-and-configure-bumblebee.html

Comment: That link might die one day. Please add a summary here of what that link says.

Answer (score 0):

If you are set to dual-boot, you might also see if suspend works correctly in Windows.

I have a different model Lenovo laptop. Mine (E540) and another model (E440) have a [BIOS bug](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/11e-Windows-E-and-Edge-series/E540-Suspend-Resume-failure/td-p/1780813) that has a very similar sounding effect. (On my model, the workaround is to turn off USB3.0 in the BIOS settings.)

If you confirm the problem affects only linux, I hope you raise a stink with Lenovo in their support forums, or through the place you bought it. Lenovo has a reputation for supporting linux, but things like this imply their stance has changed and they don't even test linux anymore.

[Here's the Lenovo forum for your model laptop.](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-P-Y-and-Z-series/bd-p/ll04_en) I see there are lots of topics mentioning suspend, so you might look through those for recommendations from other users, and open a thread of your own if you don't see one that matches.